# JMX Operation with File parameter not active

Tags: spring, jmx, jconsole, operation

I am successfully exposing a method using the Spring annotations:

```
@Override
@ManagedOperation(description = "synchronize To Local Directory")
@ManagedOperationParameters({ @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "localDirectory", description = "The Local Directory") }
public void synchronizeToLocalDirectory(File localDirectory) {
    super.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(localDirectory);
}
```

By successful I mean that it can be seen in jConsole.
However, the operation cannot be invoked, obviously because the parameter; localDirectory, needs to be specified.

localDirectory is of type File.

The problem is that the button/option to set the localDirectory in the invocation of the operation is not active.

If I change the type from File to String it works, but I do not want to do that - I preferably want the user to choose a directory via a file chooser dialog.

Questions:
Does JMX cater for a File type parameter in a operation that can be specified in something like jConsole? Or does it have to be setup as a Composite type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No `java.io.File` is not a directly supported JMX type. As you are correctly suggesting you need to either use a composite type or adjust the management interface to accept eg. `String` value of the file path.